# How to define custom Controller in XAML Plot

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I have 2 questions about oxyplot and since they are very simple, I put them together:

1. How can I define custom plot Controller in XAML? I noticed there is a *Controller* property in *PlotView* class, but there is nothing I could find in the *Plot* class. Am I missing something, or it's not possible at the moment?
2. <s>Does maximum range property work on a *DateTimeAxis*? What are the units? I have tried values around hundreds or thousands, but it seems that the zoom is not limited.</s>

My plot is defined in the XAML as follows:

```
<oxy:Plot>
    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:DateTimeAxis Title="Time" Position="Bottom" StringFormat="HH:mm:ss" />
        <oxy:LinearAxis Title="Temperature" Position="Left" Key="Temperature" />
        <oxy:LogarithmicAxis Title="Pressure" Position="Right" Key="Pressure" />
    </oxy:Plot.Axes>
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:LineSeries Title="Temperature" ItemsSource="{Binding Temperatures, Mode=OneWay}" DataFieldY="Temperature" YAxisKey="Temperature" />
        <oxy:LineSeries Title="Pressure" ItemsSource="{Binding Pressures, Mode=OneWay}" DataFieldY="Pressure" YAxisKey="Pressure" />
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

Comment: After some experimentation I can now answer the second part of the question on my own. _DateTimeAxis_ apparently uses double representation of dates, where **1 = day**. So I was able to set the maximum zoom of my plot to 12 hours by setting it to 0.5. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding custom controller via XAML seems impossible, so I have used `System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior` to edit plot's controller without code behind.

Behavior is defined like this:

```
public class CustomControllerPlotBehavior : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<Plot>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomizeController(AssociatedObject.ActualController);
    }

    private void CustomizeController(IPlotController controller)
    {
        controller.UnbindAll();

        // actual changes to the controller
        controller.BindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Left, OxyModifierKeys.Shift, PlotCommands.ZoomRectangle);
        controller.BindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Left, OxyModifierKeys.Control, PlotCommands.PanAt);
        controller.BindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Left, PlotCommands.SnapTrack);
        controller.BindKeyDown(OxyKey.Home, PlotCommands.Reset);
        controller.BindMouseWheel(PlotCommands.ZoomWheel);
        controller.BindMouseWheel(OxyModifierKeys.Control, PlotCommands.ZoomWheelFine);
    }
}
```

In XAML, the behavior can be used like this:

```
<oxy:Plot>
    <!-- Other plot settings -->
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:CustomControllerPlotBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</oxy:Plot>
```